# Ubuntu doesn't boot and boot-repair-disk doesn't solve the problem

Tags: 12.04, boot, grubrescue, boot-repair, initramfs

The problem started with a little graphic problem and evolved to a Ubuntu 12.04 that doesn't boot. Instead, it led me to a command-like screen with the word Initramfs. After that I tried to fix it by a USB-Live Boot-Repair-Disk, but I didnt get any luck from that, and now I dont even get the screen with Initramfs anymore. Now I get the "error: file not found GRUB rescue. What can I do to repair the OS, or should I just reinstall the whole system?
Thanks a lot

I got this report from the Boot-Reapir-Disk. 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7341382/

Comment: you can try the steps given at this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

```
sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:
```

It seems like all your datas in the Ubuntu partition(ext4) is accidentally deleted. So try to reinstall it on any one of the ext4 partition.